# Calculating ${O_{K,S}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S}^{\times}}^2$ for $S$-unit of imaginary quadratic number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a imaginary quadratic number field which is not $ \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}), \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.
Let $S=\{2,17\}$ be places of $K$.
Let $O_{K,S} \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\{a\in K \mid v(a)\ge 0, 
\forall v\notin S\}$.

I want to know when $\sharp {O_{K,S}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S}^{\times}}^2=8$.
This holds for $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ for $D=-3,-5,-11,-29,-37,-61,-107,-173,-317,-397,-541,-853,-2621$.
according to Sage Math.

My try :

Let $S'$ be set of prime elements of $K$ above $2,17$. According to Neukirhi's $Cor 11.7$, ${O_{K,S'}}^{\times}\cong μ(K)×\Bbb{Z}^{\#S'+r+s-1}$
where $r$ is the number of real embedding, $s$ is the number of imaginary embedding, and $μ(K)$ is group of unity.
In this situation, $r=0,s=1$, $μ(K)=\{±1\}$.
Thus,
${O_{K,S'}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S'}^{\times}}^2 \cong \frac{\{±1\}×{\Bbb{Z}}^2}{0×2\Bbb{Z}^2}\cong  (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^3$

But I cannot proceed from here because I cannot find the relation between ${O_{K,S}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S}^{\times}}^2$ and ${O_{K,S'}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S'}^{\times}}^2$.

> P.S
>
> Why $2,17$ does not split implies $\sharp
> > {O_{K,S}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S}^{\times}}^2=8$ ?

Comment: $K$ defines $r$ and $s$, so implicitly it depends on $K$. For imaginary quadratics you don't have a lot of choice for $r,s$, which constraints your outcome. Though I am not sure if the corollary stands for other fields where primes in $S$ ramify (say $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$)? Seems like there should be no difference, but I'm a bit rusty on number theory.

Comment: $r=0, s=1$ always holds in this case, so the condition that $\sharp {O_{K,S}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S}^{\times}}^2 =8$ is $2,17$ is inserts in $K$ ?

Comment: Or ramified. You just need $|S|=2$.

Comment: You mean $\mid S' \mid=2$ ?

Comment: @Aphelli. When $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$, sage reads  $\sharp  {O_{K,S}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S}^{\times}}^2=16$.

Comment: Yes, $|S’|=2$. Note that $2$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ but $17$ splits there.

Comment: THen, when $2,17$ does not split, $\sharp {O_{K,S'}}^{\times}/{O_{K,S'}^{\times}}^2=8$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake comes from not distinguishing primes in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{K}$, that is, not distinguishing $S$ and $S'.$  There is no $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K},S}$, this ring is only defined for prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{K}$.  Implicitly $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}, S} := \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}, S'}$ where $S'$ is the set of primes over $S$.

While $\# S = 2$, we have $\#S' \geq 2$ depending on the splitting of $2,17$ in $\mathbb{K}$, and this is where dependence on $\mathbb{K}$ comes in.

As you  rightly noted, when $2$ splits, and $17$ doesn't split, you have ${\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K},S'}^{\times}}/{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K},S'}^{\times}}^2=16$ which comes from $\# S' = 3$. You can find similar examples where $\#S'=4$ and the order of the group becomes $32$.

In particular the result reads as
$$
{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K},S'}^{\times}}/{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K},S'}^{\times}}^2 \cong  (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^{1 + \#S'} = \begin{cases}{
(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^{3} \text{ if $2,17$ don't split in }\mathbb{K}, \\
(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^{4} \text{ if exactly one of $2,17$ splits in }\mathbb{K}, \\
(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^{5 } \text{ if both $2,17$ split in }\mathbb{K}.}
\end{cases}
$$